# Column Name on CreatedCell at DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm working with DataTable and trying to do something like this

```
    columnDefs: [{
      "targets": '_all',
      "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        alert("You are in column: " + Columns[col].name);
       }
    }]
```

what I need is the name of the column where is the cell that's being created. As for now I know that col has its index, but I dont really know how to work it from there. rowData seems to help as it has as properties the columns of the table but don't really know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access this information from the table's [`settings`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/settings()) object - but bear in mind this is an **internal DataTables object**, which you should only use if there is no other official API call you can use instead.

Assuming you have a table with the following ID:

```
<table id="example"></table>
```

then you can use this:

```js
columnDefs: [{
  "targets": '_all',
  "createdCell": function (cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    var colInfo = $('#example').DataTable().settings()[0].aoColumns[colIndex];
    console.log( "This column has the following title: " + colInfo.sTitle );
    console.log( "This column has the following name: " + colInfo.sName );
   }
}]
```

This shows how to access both [title](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) and [name](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name) - pick the one you need!

I have not seen a better way to access either of these - but if there is one, then that would be preferable to this approach.

Comment: did not have the "#Example" id but could use "$(This)" as te context where I was working was the DataTalbe Itself. What I needed exactly was the DataTable().settings()[0].aoColumns[colIndex] line.

Thank you very much! =)